# How to design Data Access layer in Entity Framework (Data First)

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, data-access-layer

I am working on an enterprise solutions and we are using EF data first for our data access layer. Currently we have around 100 tables in database and we are adding them to one Entity data model. As project will grow we are going to have one big entity data model with around 500 tables.

We are planning to create small modules for each component of application and creating separate entity data model for each.If somebody has experience of this approach then Please share pros and cons of it.

Comment: Please take some time to find out which kind of questions are fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GertArnold: Thanks for your suggestion but what's the problem with this question. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want service layer if not then you can directly create EDMX with 500 tables. Entity Framework will support. 
The only issue you will face is - you wont be able to open EDMX file in design mode. You have to deal with it in xml format only. 
Also, you need to disable code generation for every time so that project can be load easily.

Comment: Thanks for providing information. Yes, we have web api service layer which is calling EF data access layer. So can we go with separate EF data model so that we don't have to work in xml format and disable code generation. Also if you have some rough idea for how many tables EF will handle the load easily.